# Python how to check if last element in for loop?

Tags: python

Following code given:

```
...
libera_client = libera_get_client(endpoint=endpoint, access_key=access_key, secret_key=secret_key, region=region)
libera_transfer = s3transfer.create_transfer_manager(libera_transfer_client, transfer_config)
all_segments_uploaded = False
retry_list = []
while not all_segments_uploaded:
    upload = None
    if len(retry_list) > 0:
        for src, dst in [(p[0], p[1]) for p in retry_list]:
            upload = libera_transfer.upload(fileobj=src, bucket=bucket, key=dst,
                                            subscribers=[s3transfer.ProgressCallbackInvoker(progress_func)])
    else:
        for src, dst in [(p[0], p[1]) for p in upload_list]:
            upload = libera_transfer.upload(fileobj=src, bucket=bucket, key=dst,
                                            subscribers=[s3transfer.ProgressCallbackInvoker(progress_func)])
    upload.result()   # This is just to wait for the upload to be finished
    for src, dst in [(p[0], p[1]) for p in enumerate(upload_list)]:
        print(f'HEAD Object validation of upload: {dst}')
        try:
            libera_client.head_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=dst, ChecksumMode='ENABLED')
        except ClientError as e:
            all_segments_uploaded = False
            retry_list.append([src, dst])
            print(f'Integrity check failed with: {e}, Upload will get reinitialized until completion!')
            if len(upload_list[:-1]):
                break
            else:
                continue
        all_segments_uploaded = True

libera_transfer.shutdown()

return libera_transfer
```

How can I properly check if I'm handling the last element in my for loop?
As soon as the last element is reached, I want to break.

Comment: I don't understand. How is breaking at the end of the last iteration of the loop helping you? If it is the last iteration, the loop will stop anyhow?

Comment: Why can't you let your loop to run to its end?

Comment: If `upload_list` really is a list, you can just gets its length before the loop starts, then compare that to `src`. (As an aside, `for src, dst in enumerate(upload_list)` would be sufficient.)

Comment: `for` loop will end the loop execution once element are exhausted. So there's no need to break on last element.

Comment: Sorry for not providing the full code, there is much boiler stuff around it, I cannot explain right away. So I just placed this snipped.

Comment: I just added some more stuff to question, maybe it's more clear now what I'm trying to achieve here. I first upload all stuff, then I check if I get back the HEAD of each uploaded file, if not add the object I was not able to get the HEAD for to the retry list and basically for loop on this at the next run of while not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your scenario you are using `enumerate` and you want to `break` at last element of `for` so you can check the index returned by `enumerate` and length of `upload_list`.

`enumerate` returns `index` and `element` so you can compare index and length of `upload_list`

```py
for src, dst in [(p[0], p[1]) for p in enumerate(upload_list)]:
        print(src,dst)
        if len(upload_list)-1==src:
            print("last")
            break
```

and you can directly unpack enumerate as follows:

```py
for src, dst in enumerate(upload_list):
        print(src,dst)
        if len(upload_list)-1==src:
            print("last")
            break
```

PS. `for` loop will stop iterating once all the element in iterator are exhausted. If possible please state your use case for such manual behavior to give clarity.

Comment: Now I get: botocore.exceptions.ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed: Invalid type for parameter Key, value:  ['/tmp/output/1 testfile.txt', 'Temp/1 testfile.txt'] type: <class 'list'>, valid types: <class 'str'>

Comment: That's the error from `boto3` stating that you have passed wrong parameter in the function it suggests you to pass `str` format and not `list`. For this I would like to suggest debug it or open new question for this error. If your `Python how to check if last element in for loop?` is solved please select the Answer which solved your doubt.

Comment: I'm with you, but without your code I don't have this issue and libera_client.head_object triggers fine.

Comment: As per my suggested answer. I'm not changing any data-type or something. As per the error shown `Key` parameter of `libera_client.head_object` is getting this value `['/tmp/output/1 testfile.txt', 'Temp/1 testfile.txt']` which is `dst` in code snippet. I would request you to check the value of `dst` and add comment which changes you made

Comment: To me it seems that both strings src and dst and packed into a single string and that's also why we get this key error here.

Comment: It might be the case that `dst` is having `list` in latter elements because your code snippet was as follows: `if update_list[:-1]: break` and this statement will be true because there's some value in it and hence you were exiting the `for` loop without iterating it whole and now after correction you encountered new error. It's classic **one solved, one pops**. If current doubt is solved please mark the solution as Answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using index number and iterate, iterate until last element, I think that should work

```
    for i in range(len(upload_list)): # iterate whole list using index value
        src = upload_list[i][0] 
        dst = upload_list[i][1] 
        print(f'HEAD Object validation of upload: {dst}')
        try:
            libera_client.head_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=dst, ChecksumMode='ENABLED')
        except ClientError as e:
            all_segments_uploaded = False
            retry_list.append([src, dst])
            print(f'Integrity check failed with: {e}, Upload will get reinitialized until completion!')
            if (i == len(upload_list)-1): # so you check here, if current index is equal to last index or not
                break
            else:
                continue
        all_segments_uploaded = True
```

Comment: Have you checked my updated question? Is it now more clear?

Comment: check my post now, iterate over whole list, then if exception occurs, check if index number with if condition, then break

Comment: If i do 
```
if (i == len(upload_list) - 1):
     print("iefnwoienfoiwef")
     break
```
I'll never reach the print statement

Answer (score 0):

yo ucan  save the iterator in a list instead using in for loop and then pass len(iterator)-1 data  only

```
data = [(p[0], p[1]) for p in enumerate(upload_list)]
len_data = len(data)

for index, (src, dest) in enumerate(data[:-1])
     # rest of code
# or 

for index, (src, dest) in enumerate(data):
     if index ==len_data-1:
           break
     # rest of code
```

Answer (score 0):

A friend of mine came to the solution to shrink the list and fill the retry list with the remaining of the upload_list. This has shortened the code and does the job as intended:

```
libera_client = libera_get_client(endpoint=endpoint, access_key=access_key, secret_key=secret_key, region=region)
libera_transfer = s3transfer.create_transfer_manager(libera_transfer_client, transfer_config)
all_segments_uploaded = False
while not all_segments_uploaded:
    retry_list = []
    upload = None

    for src, dst in [(p[0], p[1]) for p in upload_list]:
        upload = libera_transfer.upload(fileobj=src, bucket=bucket, key=dst,
                                        subscribers=[s3transfer.ProgressCallbackInvoker(progress_func)])
    upload.result()
    for src, dst in [(p[0], p[1]) for p in upload_list]:
        print(f'HEAD Object validation of upload: {dst}')
        try:
            libera_client.head_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=dst, ChecksumMode='ENABLED')
        except ClientError as e:
            retry_list.append([src, dst])
            print(f'Integrity check failed with: {e}, Upload will get reinitialized until completion!')
            all_segments_uploaded = False
    if len(retry_list) > 0:
        upload_list = retry_list
    else:
        all_segments_uploaded = True

libera_transfer.shutdown()

return libera_transfer
```

I won't mark this a solution, as it does not really handle the original question (get the last element in a list).

Comment: This is an extremely complicated answer for a relatively simple question. Also, the shared code doesn't seem to answer the question: `is this the last element in the loop?`

Comment: It does not solve the original question, but it solves the original problem, I just thought it would be a nice show-case for others that are maybe in a similar situation as both solution are basically working on a list. Why extremely complicated? Its efficient and besides damn fast.